# csrf token missing pgadmin via nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using postgres, pgadmin, nginx docker images, also using gunicorn and launching using docker-compose.

I am able to do following things sucessfully as below:

1. All services are up and running.
2. Able to login pgadmin(via nginx).
3. Able to create server and fired queries on database.

Issue is: when I click on logout button.
Although, I am able to logout and redirected to login page. But on terminal, I am getting error which is not constant sometimes it is

1. ERROR pgadmin: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
2. ERROR pgadmin: The CSRF token do not match.

I tried many solutions on googling but none of them worked.
I also observed following things:

1. I viewed login page source code, there is csrf_token with long string.
2. In request header, 'X-pgA-CSRFToken' with long string(both same)

My pgadmin section from nginx conf file as below:

```
location /pgadmin4 {   

    proxy_cookie_flags ~ secure nohttponly samesite=none;
    proxy_pass http://pgadmin:8081;       

}
```

I am unable to figure out, what is wrong.